# jquery header selector not working

Tags: jquery

html...

```
<div>
    <h1>heading one</h1>
    <p>para one</p>
    <h2>heading two</h2>
    <p>para two</p>
    <h3>heading three</h3>
    <p>para three</p>
</div>
```

jquery....

```
$( ":header" ).css({ background: "#ccc", color: "blue" }); // this works
```

But these not, why?

```
$( "div:header" ).css({ background: "#ccc", color: "blue" });
```

or

```
$("div").filter( ":header" ).css({ background: "#ccc", color: "blue" });
```

I wanted to use `:header` selector for particular div only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector)/[child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector)

```
$( "div :header" ).css({ background: "#ccc", color: "blue" });
```

or [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find)

```
$("div").find( ":header" ).css({ background: "#ccc", color: "blue" });
```

because the header elements are descendants of the div element.

When you use `div:header` or `.filter()`, it searches for a `div` element which is also a header element which will never be true